# Does Deadpool ever need surgery?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

OK, we all know that Deadpool has regenerative powers, but is there ever a situation where he would need surgery so as he heals correctly.

Being a Doctor I have always wondered how the process works for him when he has a more complicated fracture such as

- multifragmentary fracture  (broken into more than two pieces)
- impacted fracture    (at least one bone or fragment of bone has been driven into another)
- compression fracture   (When bone becomes like pebbles)

All of these breaks require outside forces for the bones to mend in the correct manner in ordinary people.

As we are shown in the Deadpool movie, he does not heal at rate like Wolverine, but does in my opinion get a compound fracture (clean bone break) in his leg. And I would speculate that he **MAY** have recived a multifragmentary fracture in his hands after hitting Colossus.

It seems that he can align the bones to heal correctly judging by his wrist snap when Colossus is dragging him. But in the more complicated fractures, does he need medical attention?

**Is there cases where he would need surgery?**

Comment: There is a situation where he completely melts and regenerates from it without outside help. You get the feeling I get when I'm watching Person of Interest as ab IT guy. It's... magic.

Comment: Would evidence from the comics be acceptable?

Comment: @Politank-Z, regenerating from a pulp I know about, so anything that will show how he regenerates with everything healing as it was before will be OK. So yes, comics are OK.

Comment: There's a scene in one of the recent DP comics (within the past year--I'm too lazy to go find it again) where he superglues his hand back on instead of waiting for it to just grow back. Surgery seems to help but isn't always required.

Answer (score 3):

Both Wolverine(when he had no Adamantium) and Deadpool have stated to observers that their bones mend just as any normal persons would, so if were bent, they would have to move them back into place before the bones finish knitting together.  However artistic license allows for the fact that some bones can't be held in place (size, location etc), so they just have the healing factor automatically knit the bones in the correct place.

Comment: I think there was a case in the comic where all that was left of him was a severed hand, the rest was destroyed somehow, and he regenerated whole from just he hand.  I'm pretty sure silly things like broken bones are no challenge regardless of what it takes for us normals to heal them clean.

Comment: I don't suppose you happen to remember where Wolverine stated that. We have a similar question recently.