# If Wolverine broke a bone which protruded his skin, what would happen if he started to heal before it was set and splinted?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

In *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* we see that Wolverine’s bones can be broken in the fight between him and Sabretooth.

So if he was to suffer an injury (let's say a very high fall) and broke his leg and the bone snapped and came through the skin (an open break), what would be the effect of his healing powers if the bone wasn't reset and splinted?

Comment: While it's not the exact same question, one of the answers to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137903/does-deadpool-ever-need-surgery states that Wolverine has said that his bones heal normally and need to be re-set, but they don't say where he said that.

Comment: In the [*Wild Cards 'verse,*](http://www.wildcardsonline.com/characters-d.html) one fast-healing character (Demise) had his healing ability used against him, with an even-worse bad guy breaking his limbs and forcing them to heal crookedly.

Comment: I always assumed the reason they gave him the "unbreakable" skeleton in the first place, is so they wouldn't have to deal with those kind of issues.

Comment: Why, if that happened, Wolverine would just re-break and reset them while chewing on his stogie.

Answer (score 4):

Wolverine can regenerate fully. That means while he has even a single cell alive, he can regenerate from it. This already happened once. A single cell will re-create his skeleton, muscles, and skin.

That means a single cell knows how Wolverine is, and every cell retains his "blueprint" so to speak.

In your case, I'm guessing that would also mean his body would pull itself together. The bone would adjust to the right place, and the muscle and skin heal shut. But this raise worm-split-in-half questions.

I'm discussing Wolverine at the peak of his mutant powers. It's usual for his powers to vary greatly from author to author. Hulk split Wolverine in half once, and threw his legs hundreds of miles away. In that universe, Wolverine had to crawl over to them to fuse and heal his lower body.

Comment: In some continuities, Deadpool's healing factor (at least initially) was based on Wolverine's, and at one point, Deadpool has to be put on a rack to rebreak and straighten bones that had healed crookedly, so that might give an answer.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots sounds lke you're on to somthing!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there exist an exact answer as all this depends on the movie, comic, producer ...

For example, in [Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_(TV_series)), [Claire Bennet](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claire_Bennet) has the same kind of healing as Wolverine. She can heal any wound and is immortal.

There is an episode where she broke a rib and the bone was outside the skin. She couldn't heal until she introduced the bone herself inside again. Then the wound was perfectly cured.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but *Heroes* is pretty different from Marvel Comics. Besides, if Claire’s healing abilities vis-à-vis broken bones have been consistently portrayed in this regard, I’d be mildly surprised.

Comment: Sometimes, for example, she’s walked away from falls that must certainly have caused many open fractures, without having to push all the bones back into the right place. Perhaps her ability developed over time somewhat.